# Turn Based App Multiplayer Options

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am building a simple two player turn based game on android:

I have been reviewing the awesome API that google provides for multiplayer games on Android:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer

I was going to use it, until I discovered the users need to have a Google+ account.  That is not going to work, because it will limit my audience drastically, for my online app.

So now I am considering using Google Cloud Messaging (with XMPP), but that will require me to build and maintain my own app server.

Questions: 
Just to confirm, if I used google play services for my turn based game, I would have to ask the user to sign into, or register for google+?
Are there any other reliable peer to peer options for my online android app that don't require the user to do some sign in? 
If not, is GCM with XMPP the best way to accomplish turn based networking?

Answer (score 1):

I made an app using the turn-based multiplayer api. It doesn't limit your players at all I think. All you need is a gmail. And I think the vast majority of people use gmail.

Not to mention, depending on your app, you can incorporate AI for single player if some one REALLY doesnt want to use google+

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it this is sort of a "chicken and egg" scenario. In order to download your app from the Play Store you need a Google account, so anyone who downloads your app will most likely already have a Google+ account which is required for the Google Play Multiplayer API and also to review your app.

If this is still a concern, then you will need to set up your own server. I would recommend [SmartFoxServer](http://smartfoxserver.com/) for this as it supports everything that the Google Play Multiplayer API does such as iOS and web.

Comment: I am fine with using it, if all you really need is a google account. Are you sure you don't have to sign up for google plus separately?

Comment: It really depends on what features you plan to use. Sign-in is not essential for the API, but having a Google+ account allows you to take advantage of extra features like friends list etc. It states "Improve registration by letting players sign in with their Google account."